# TRANSACT SQL - How to manually order/index a table based upon a select/where statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have sql puzzler today.

I have the following sql :

```
  SELECT MemberId, 
         UnitId, 
         MaterialLevel, 
         MaterialText, 
         ProductPercentage, 
         ProductPriority
    FROM tblWeights
ORDER BY MemberId, MaterialLevel, MaterialText, ProductPercentage DESC
```

Now, currently the ProductPriority is empty. What I would like to do is update this so that the first product, per level, per materialtext with the highest product percentage with "1", the second highest percentage with "2", etc, etc.

However, when the materialtext changes, this should reset itself and and start again at "1".

Can anyone think how I can do this?

Comment: Do you look for a SELECT query with a specific sort order, or an actual UPDATE query?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?  If so, what version?  Sounds like a job for analytics...

Comment: It is an update query, I just popped the select in there to show the ordering.

This is running on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Tomalak, did you have a chance to investigate my Answer? I think it's a pretty decent shot at a not so common and not so trivial puzzle. I would love to hear your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you want productpriority explicitly stored in the database? Sorry if I've misunderstood your question but this sounds like it could be handled with a straight ROW_NUMBER in the output query.

Comment: Row count does seem to be the best solution.  The only reason not to go with it is if they want to index the column and do searches on it. That would seem unlikely though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the initial update:

```
UPDATE tblWeights w1
SET    ProductPriority = (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   tblWeights w2
           WHERE  w2.level        = w1.level
           AND    w2.materialText = w1.materialText
           AND    w2.ProductPercentage >= w1.ProductPercentage
       )
```

For the automatic reset, you should probably write a trigger that fires at the statement level after `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. You can use a modified version of this statement, and only update the rows having  the affected level,materialtext combination

```
CREATE TRIGGER aiud_tblWeights ON tblWeights 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
IF( UPDATE (Level) OR UPDATE (MaterialText) )
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblWeights w1
    SET    ProductPriority = (
               SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM   tblWeights w2
               WHERE  w2.level        = w1.level
               AND    w2.materialText = w1.materialText
               AND    w2.ProductPercentage >= w1.ProductPercentage
           )
    WHERE  (w1.level, w1.materialText) IN (
        SELECT level, materialText
        FROM   inserted
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT level, materialText
        FROM   deleted
    );        
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late. but I found one answer when I was looking for similar questions for my help. see if helps someone else.

[SQL query results to be displayed in the order of the manually provided values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426439/1005741)