# SQL query results to be displayed in the order of the manually provided values

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a database of loyalty card holders. I'm trying to write a simple SQL query that retrieves the full name of a customer based on his card number. However, I specifically need the output to be **in the exact order I add the card numbers in**. How can I implement this?

Here's what I did.

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name FROM cardholder WHERE
cardnumber LIKE '%1111%' OR
cardnumber LIKE '%2222%' OR
cardnumber LIKE '%3333%'
```

I should add that I'm not very familiar with SQL, what I know now is pretty much the result of googling this particular problem in the past few days.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

*(Also, I would be grateful for a way in which the card numbers can just be pasted into the code as a single block of text, but that's only bonus.)*

Comment: do you mean the order you added the card numbers to the database, or the order you specify them in your query?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant the order I specify them in the query, like the way you see them in the code above.

Comment: @Andrew, not sure where you live, but you **do** know that it is illegal in many countries to store creditcard data unencrypted?

Comment: @Johan, these are loyalty cards at an oil company. You can collect loyalty points on them.

Comment: @Andrew, I still would advice strongly against storing personal data unencrypted, if your data leaks you'll have a problem on your hands. If encrypted data leaks the issue will be far less.

Comment: @Johan, thank you for your concern, but unfortunately this is way beyond my range at this company. If I planned a database like this for my own enterprise, using encryption wouldn't be a question, but here it really is not my sphere of action. I'm just trying to work efficiently with the tools I get. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name 
FROM (
     SELECT cardnumber, first_name, last_name, c.OrderNo
     FROM cardholder ch, (SELECT '%1111%' cardmask, 1 OrderNo from dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT '%2222%', 2 OrderNo from dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT '%3333%', 3 OrderNo from dual
                        ) c
     WHERE ch.cardnumber LIKE c.cardmask
     Order by c.OrderNo
) t
```

Comment: Do you need an alias name for the sub-query being selected from?  And should the ORDER BY be moved out of the sub-query to the main query?

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but I get an error that the table doesn't exist. Could you please let me know what parts of your code are to be changed and what parts are to stay intact? I'm really unfamiliar with SQL. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew, check that table cardholder exists and you use oracle.

Comment: my bad, it actually is named otherwise, I just forgot to rename it. Now your code works like a charm, thank you very much! It's really appreciated. The only problem that's left is in this form it's rather complicated to input the card numbers when there are hundreds of them. The way I wrote it I could do two simple replaces and the query was ready. It got a bit more difficult now. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add a custom ORDER BY clause.  Something like

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name 
  FROM cardholder 
 WHERE cardnumber LIKE '%1111%' OR
       cardnumber LIKE '%2222%' OR
       cardnumber LIKE '%3333%'
 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN cardnumber LIKE '%1111%' THEN 1
                WHEN cardnumber LIKE '%2222%' THEN 2
                WHEN cardnumber LIKE '%3333%' THEN 3
                ELSE 4
            END) asc
```

Comment: thank you very much indeed. This one works, too, and it looks clean enough to be possibly more suitable for solving the manual input issue I previously wrote to Michael about.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of auto-incremented id column used as a primary key in your "cardholder" table? If yes, and the column is "id", you could just use

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name FROM cardholder ORDER BY id
```

This will sort your card number in the order they were inserted in the database.

Your example shows that your are trying to sort your card numbers incrementally, so maybe what you are searching for is

```
SELECT cardnumber, first_name || ' ' || last_name FROM cardholder ORDER BY cardnumber
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: Hum, I understand better your question now, this is apparently not what you are searching for...

Comment: It isn't, but thank you anyway. The example might have been misleading.